# Reproduce scripts breakpoint using casperjs and phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a webpage that loads a `.js` file at start. This script redirects to another page, after making some tests.

I need to reproduce the following steps using `casperjs` / `phantomjs`.

In real browser:

- open the website,
- set a breakpoint (using Chrome dev console) at one line of that file, before the redirection,
- refresh (after that the script execution stops at that point)
- run some js code I need in console
- resume the script execution

Here is what I tried:

```
casper.start( url );
casper.on("page.initialized", function(response){
    this.evaluate(function(){
       // the code I need to run before redirection ...
       // it never enters in here
    });
});
casper.run( function() {
    casper.exit();
});
```

or

```
casper.start( url );
casper.then( function() {
    this.evaluate(function(){
       // the code I need to run before redirection ...
    });
});
casper.run( function() {
    casper.exit();
});
```

When I run that code in console: `./phantomjs script.js` I see in console the following lines:

1.

`[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: [WEBSITE_URL]`

and

2.

```
[debug] [phantom] url changed to [NEW_URL]
[debug] [phantom] start page is loaded
```

so maybe I should find a way to run my js code right between 1. and 2.

What do you think? Do you have any idea?

Thanks!

**Edit**:

I tried (as suggested):

```
casper.on("page.resource.requested", function(requestData, request){
    casper.evaluate(function(){
       // the code I need to run before redirection ...
    });
});
```

but the problem is still that it does not enter the `evaluate` function.

Comment: Since you can't simply insert `debugger;` statements in the page JavaScript, what is it that you actually what to achieve? Be aware of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/266187). Do you want to run the code immediately before the redirection or just sometime before?

Comment: @ArtjomB. for me both solutions could be fine. I just need some ideas or tips to do something like that.

Comment: Have you tried to use the [`page.resource.received` event](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-resource-received)? It could work better than `page.initialized`. Also, how are you validating that what you wanted to do actually happened?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I tried that, but it does not work, see my edit please. Thanks

Comment: Ok, that is strange. How are you testing if `evaluate` function is entered? Note that `console.log` would need an event listener on the CasperJS-side, `casper` is not available inside, and `this` refers to `window` and not `casper`